# How can I escape /n/t/t/t in htmlagalitypack

Tags: parsing, dom, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I wanna parse affected versions table from [cvedetails.com](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2019-16223/) via html-agility-pack. I wrote a code like below. I get the table's raw HTML through the puppeteer. via (VulnerabilityParser.GetAffectedVersionAsync () function)

```
string versionsTableRawHTML = await VulnerabilityParser.GetAffectedVersionAsync(AffectedVersionsSelector);

        var versionsTable = new HtmlDocument();
        versionsTable.LoadHtml(versionsTableRawHTML);

        foreach (HtmlNode table in versionsTable.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr/td"))
        {
            var row= table.SelectSingleNode("//tr/td[5]").InnerText;           
        }
```

That result the following falls to my row variable.
"\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"

I checked  on the target site. It's not in it.
What is the reason of this result? How should I parse this?

Answer (score 0):

To get rows of the table you can follow the bellow approach

```
  HtmlWeb mWb = new HtmlWeb();

         HtmlDocument mDoc= mWb.Load("https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2019-16223/");

        var rows = mDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='num']");

        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            //Each row number
            Console.WriteLine(row.InnerText);
        }
```

To get other columns you can follow a same approach and split all rows in a for loop with length 700